# Seven octahedral nets to cover an octahedron

Tags: geometry, tiling, three-dimensional, paper-folding

After solving [Cover a single cube with FIVE identical cube nets](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118725/75318) I had the idea for this puzzle, which may be regarded as a natural generalisation to triangular grids.

Find two different nets, A and B, of a regular octahedron such that these two collections of nets can each be folded into the surface of a single regular octahedron with *seven* times the surface area of the original octahedron:

- 3 copies of A and 4 of B
- 6 copies of A and 1 of B

Restrictions from the five-cubes-to-cube puzzle apply analogously:

- A and B must be formed by cutting along the original octahedron's edges (so they are octiamonds). All small nets are of the same size.
- The nets are one-sided. Suppose one side of each net is painted, then all copies of A must be identical without flipping when the painted side is up, and similarly for B. The large octahedra formed by both net collections must show only painted faces.
- The large octahedra must have no gaps or overlaps in them.

As a hint, A and B differ by only one triangle.

> A and B are also totally asymmetric (not rotation/reflection-symmetric).

> If one triangle is removed from net A the remaining heptiamond has the symmetries of a triskelion. Net B can be decomposed into two Pac-Man-shaped tetriamonds.

Comment: My goodness this is a tough one!

Comment: @plasticinsect I found no solutions using only one kind of net or a net and its mirror image. This was a choice pick over all 2-net combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is already a 6A + 1B covering.

> [image]

With the same shapes there is a 2A + 5B covering.

> [image]

[edit: Except that, as Parcly mentions, it doesn't satisfy the one-sided rule...]

But I don't know about 3A + 4B...

Update: I found a second covering with the same shapes, that respects chirality

> [image]
>
>  But it is 5A + 2B.  And since it is the result of a computer search
>  it seems these 2 shapes won't do.

**Finally**

The new hints restrict a lot what shape to look for.  There were just two possible pairs, (i.e. 2 orientations) and only one of them yields a solution.  The solutions happen to be composed of 6A + 1B

> [image]

and 3A + 4B.

> [image]

Below you can find the OP's solutions.  It is bound to be the same solutions but in a very different presentation.

> [image]
>  (From OP) The code that found this tiling pair can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Parcly-Taxel/dc680287932ea4758e1ebf0460c78c2d).

Comment: Funny, I recall answering that, but I don't know where.  It is a basic paint program called acorn.  It is probably less advanced than you think.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I'll check it out.